# Save word as string

Tags: c, arrays

Need to save word and type it letter by letter.

I know its pretty easy to work it with for loop. But the problem is I don't know how much word is long i need to make a function which will count letters first. Wonder if there is easier way like this.

Current progress

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

 char word[30];
 int i;

 printf("Enter word ");
 scanf("%s", word);

while(word[i] != '\0') i++;
 printf("%c,", word[i]);

 // word backward !
 // have no idea 
}
```

Comment: The standard function is called `strlen()`. Assuming you can't use that, you can mimic it.  Your `while` loop counts the number of bytes in the string -- or would if you set `i` to zero before doing anything with it.  You can print each character in sequence by stepping through the string from position 0 to position `i-1`; you can print it in reverse by stepping through the string from position `i-1` to 0.  It would be a good idea to use `if (scanf("%29s", word) != 1) { ...report EOF and exit?... }`, where the `%29s` protects you from a buffer (stack) overflow.

Comment: Use [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: The `printf` is not actually inside the `while` loop.